# Return true or false to update activate="1" in database

Tags: php, get

ok I made a activation page 
here is its code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "GET")
{   
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$code=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['actcode']);

$tab='SELECT email, hash, activate
    FROM register WHERE email="'.$email.'"'.'AND hash="'.$code.'"'.'and activate="0"';  

$table=mysql_query($tab);

$query=mysql_num_rows($table);


if($query > 0)
{
    $up='UPDATE register
         SET activate="1"
        WHERE email="'.$email.'"';

        $update=mysql_query($up);

            if (!$update)
            {
            print " not updated<br/>";
            }
            else
            {
            print "<span class=\"active\"><strong>Account Activated.Kindly click<a href=\"login.php\"> HERE</a> to continue.</strong></</span><br/>";
            die();
            }
         }
             elseif($query <= 0)
             {
    print "<span class=\"active\"><strong>Invalid information provided, please try again.</strong></</span><br/>";
             }              

                }
```

Its is all working but my assignment is to GET know That Values in variables are coming from "GET" if GET than var a == true if true then i can update activate="1".

need help!

Comment: please be more clear about the question

Comment: I've read this thrice now and still don't know what you want.

Comment: Okay let me post my sir depends for this assignment 1 .To check values in variables are coming from $_GET if yes then a==true 
3 . if a= true then update activate="1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title really conflicts with your question but is this what you're trying to accomplish? You want to only update the value if an Email and Code is set?

Change this line:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "GET")
```

To this:

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['actcode']))
```

Comment: you r right abt title it was a mistake forgot to correct that any way to make it right ? EMAIl and code is set through "GET"

Comment: it works for me but if condition works for me like this 'if ((isset($_GET['email'])) && (isset($_GET['actcode'])))
{'

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "GET")
    {
          //your code
    }
```

too:

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['actcode']))
    {
          //your code
    }
```

Comment: Thankx for replying let me check that